# Issue with inserting timestamp values

Tags: teradata

This might be a small mistake which i am not able to figure out. Below insert is throwing error.

```
CREATE MULTISET  VOLATILE TABLE vt2
( cust_id INTEGER,
cust_page VARCHAR(100),
visit_date TIMESTAMP(0) FORMAT 'DD-MM-YYYYBHH:MI:SS')
PRIMARY INDEX(cust_id)
 ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;



 INSERT INTO vt2 VALUES( 100, 'hub_domain',01-11-2016 09:43:43)
```

Could you please help me with this.

Regards,
Amit

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: expected something like ',' or ')' between an integer and an integer 09

Comment: are you trying to insert vt1 instead of vt2?

Comment: Sorry, It vt2 only. Getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO vt2 VALUES( 100, 'hub_domain','01-11-2016 09:43:43')
```

However problem here is you are trying to use data with formating. Data will be formatted after insert.

following will work:

```
INSERT INTO vt2 VALUES( 100, 'hub_domain','2016-11-01 09:43:43')
```

or if your soruce data is mm/dd/yyyy format, remove format from DDL and try to cast while insert.

Comment: Got it thanks, always get confused with timestamp. :)